# `if` statement that doesn't execute other functions when condition is found to be false

Tags: php, if-statement, terminology

In PHP I can do this:

```
if (function1() && function2()) {
     doSomething();
}
```

If `function1()` returns false, then `function2()` will not be executed.

I have forgotten the name of this language feature... what do you call it?

Comment: If you *don't* want this behavior (want both functions to execute) use a single `&` instead.

Comment: @Ralph: That is actually kind of misleading, as & is not a logical operator in PHP but a bitwise operator. It takes advantage of the way PHP's casting works but it *can* lead to some odd bugs.

Comment: To be clear, the boolean return values of the functions are being implicitly cast to integers, and the *bitwise* `and` is being evaluated against these integers. In other words, `gettype(true && false)` will return `boolean`, but `gettype(true & false)` will return `integer`. When used in an `if` condition (or other control structures), that integer return value is then re-cast back to a boolean.

Comment: Yes, what AgentConundrum said... uses a few casts, but does work. Can you give an example where it would cause a bug (with booleans) Paolo?

Comment: @Ralph: With just booleans none really, but otherwise in function1() & function2() if function1 returns true and function2 returns 2, that would evaluate to false.

Comment: @Ralph: Just to clarify, my comment was just an explanation of the mechanics, not a defense of your coding style. If you really need to ensure an expression doesn't short circuit when you need to run a function as the second operand, then I'd advise you to run the functions first and store their results in variables that you can then use in the conditional. It's much more obvious what you're doing, and doesn't depend on (relatively) obscure language constructs that a reader might not fully comprehend.

Comment: @Agent: I wasn't suggesting your were defending me. You so rarely actually *want* all the functions to execute that... well, this usually isn't an issue. Generally, I don't think functions that perform necessary work should return booleans indicating some kind of success...those should be separate. Like.... form validation.... `Validate()` and `IsValid()` should be separate. Well... assuming the validation has effects such as producing error messages on the form......I'm going to stop talking now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called [`short-circuit evaluation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).